# cursor freeze elements when added zoom on D3 map

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I would like to add zoom on my D3 map but when I click on a node, drag and drop this, my cursor fix all elements. I added .call(d3.zoom()) but

code component from angular 4 :

```
ngOnInit(){ 
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    //this.svg = d3.select("svg");

    this.svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", "100%")
                    .attr("height", "100%")
                    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
                        let g = d3.select('svg > g');

                        g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
                    }))
                    .append("g");

    let width  = d3.select('svg').style("width");
    let height = d3.select('svg').style("height");

    width  = width.substring(0, width.length - 2);
    height = height.substring(0, height.length - 2);

    this.color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

    this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    this.render(miserables);
  }

  ticked() {
    this.link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    this.node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }

  render(graph){
    this.link = this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

    this.node = this.svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", (d)=> { return this.color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", (d)=>{return this.dragstarted(d)})
          .on("drag", (d)=>{return this.dragged(d)})
          .on("end", (d)=>{return this.dragended(d)}));

    this.node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

    this.simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ()=>{return this.ticked()});

    this.simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);  
  }

  dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) this.simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) this.simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){

  }
```

If I replace this :

```
this.svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%");
```

by this :

```
this.svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
        let g = d3.select('svg > g');

        g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }))
    .append("g");
```

Zoom works, but I have a problem when I selected a node to drag and drop, the cursor fix on all elements

My problem :
https://angular-tspcs9.stackblitz.io/

To edit :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tspcs9

Comment: I have no idea about Angular, but I think you may have event conflicts between `drag` and `zoom`. When you drag the node you need to add a `dragstart` event and stop propagation. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added :

```
.on("mousedown", function() { 
    d3.event.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

on my svg declaration :

```
this.svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
        let g = d3.select('svg > g');

        g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }))
    .append("g")
    .on("mousedown", function() { 
        d3.event.stopPropagation(); 
    });
```